# Samples of Spring Batch "use cases" listed in the documentation

Tags: spring-batch

Do we have sample implementations (source code) of the Spring Batch "use cases" listed in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/cases/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

you can find a lot of sample-jobs, steps, etc. in

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/spring-batch-samples/index.html

is that that kind of source code you've been looking for?